# Compare login credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

Hello I am working on a log in form.  I am able to sign up for an account on my website, but It doesn't allow me to log in when I type in the user name and password.  I have some code that is suppose the compare the two but for some reason is just not working.  Here is my code.  It wont for some reason even execute the while loop at the bottom of the code.  Any help would be appreciated

```
private bool CompareStrings(string string1, string string2)
{
    return String.Compare(string1, string2, true, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == 0 ? true : false;
}

public void LogInAccount(string UserName, string UserPassword, Label InvalidLogIn)
{
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Connection String";
    connection.Open();

    string compare = "select ISNULL(UserName, '') As UserName, ISNULL(UserPassword, '') As UserPassword from SignUp where UserName= @UserName";

    SqlCommand CompareUser = new SqlCommand(compare, connection);
    //SqlCommand Command2 = new SqlCommand("select * from SignUp where FirstName= @FirstName", connection);

    //Command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirsName", FirstName.Text);

    CompareUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPassword", UserPassword);
    CompareUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UserName);

    SqlDataReader dr = CompareUser.ExecuteReader();

    //string User = UserName;
    //string UserPassword = Password;

    //HtmlAnchor LogIn = (HtmlAnchor)Master.FindControl("LogIn");
    //HtmlAnchor SignUp = (HtmlAnchor)Master.FindControl("SignUp");

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (this.CompareStrings(dr["UserName"].ToString(), UserName) &&
             this.CompareStrings(dr["UserPassword"].ToString(), UserPassword))
        {
            InvalidLogIn.Visible = false;
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName, true);
        }
        else
        {
            InvalidLogIn.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your reply.  I actually tried that, and unfortunately it didn't work.  It's weird there is something that I'm just not catching on to right now

Comment: The sql code is valid (no need for the @ - that changes the whole meaning of things.

Comment: Interesting how come it's not letting a user log in.  When I debug the while loop doesn't even get executed.  Do you think maybe it has to do with something outside that code?  Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for your help, I actually figured the problem out

Answer (score 0):

Just something I'd throw out there: you really shouldn't be comparing usernames/passwords like this.

The basic idea behind login authentication is this:

1. When the password gets created, the *hashed* value is stored in a
   table
2. When a user tries to log in, they submit their password
3. The attempted password is then hashed
4. Hash(Attempt) is compared to the entry in the database.

... if I'm reading your code right, it looks like the password is stored in plain-text in SQL?  And your query retrieves the value, and then compares it in c#?

Don't get me wrong - if this is just a little personal site that only you use, and the password table only has your entry?  Then it's no problem.  But if you've got anyone else putting usernames/passwords in your site - you really need to protect their data.

Comment: Hello thanks for the input, and yes this plans to be a bigger site then just a personal site.  I was looking into on how to hash the passwords in sql database table.  Maybe you can help me.  In my markup I have the textmode = password, so that it is hidden when the user enters there password, but not sure how to get the hashed format in the table.  and after that then i want the hashed format and user name to be compared so that the user can log into the site.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Some googling will help, but here are the basics.  When a password is created, generate a random string called Salt.  Add the Salt to the password, and then feed that into a secure Hashing algorithm (such as SHA256.)  So if the user's password is "12345", and you generate "8D3kc93" as the salt, you're going to feed 123458D3kc93 into the hash algorithm - and then you're going to store that output in one column of the database, and the Salt in another.  Later, when a user wants to log in?  You get both SQL columns.  Then you add the salt to *their* guess, then Hash it - and check for a match.